# About kernel upgrade

Tags: linux-kernel

If I upgrade the kernel,will old binaries use new version of `.so` or still the old version?

**UPDATE**

Why kernel has nothing to do with `.so`?

Answer (score 3):

The kernel has nothing to do with the version of any shared objects.

**EDIT:**

Because the kernel is the kernel and shared objects are shared objects.

Comment: Do you mean kernel upgrade only modifies `/proc/kcore` ?

Comment: The kernel upgrade only changes the kernel and what comes with it.

Comment: Doesn't `what comes with it` include shared objects?

Comment: Only the VDSO stuff, which you don't have to care about.

Comment: OK,I got that now,thanks!But what if a specific `.so` is upgraded,will the old binaries that depend on it use new version automatically?

Comment: If the SONAME is appropriate, yes.

Comment: What if the binary is generated by `gcc -l libname xxx`?

Comment: Then the binary will be linked against that library.

Comment: I'm confused ,whether or not will the binary use new version of `libname` automatically?

Comment: The binary will use the library that is available that has an appropriate SONAME.